# Load Assembly of a Project

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

Hi I do not know if this is possible or not but I have a c# Project lets say `A` and I am trying to a`ccess Assembly Info of another project B` so that i can get `Method Info` of `project B` using `Reflection`. Problem is that i can not think of a way to integrate those two. Project A provides a `openFileDialogue` and it selects `.csproj` file. Reads it and extracts what files are being used in project B.

Can you suggest me a work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by using reflection. To work with reflection you'll need an assembly, not csproj (or cs files). You should look for a parser, maybe use the Roslyn APIs, that will give you information about the source code in syntax tree format.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx

Comment: I just need all the attributes used in the project. That is all. i do not need code. I have to avoid parsers.

Comment: Well, in that case, you may need to dynamically compile the source files and then work with the generated assembly. Why dont you take a look at csc.exe (c# compiler) you'll be able to emit an assembly from input files and then load the assembly and work with it using reflection. 
If you dont wanna use any parser,I think that this approach could work...

Comment: if accuracy is taken into account what is better CSC or Roslyn. Accuracy interms of detection of all attributes

Comment: In terms of accuracy I'll say that both are the same. The difference is in how to handle the output result. With Roslyn yo'll have to work against an AST while with csc you can get an assembly and go type.getmethods. etc, etc...

Comment: If you have never work with Roslyn you may like the option two better.

Answer (score 1):

Each .csproj file is XML, so you can read that in pretty easily. Listed in that file is every file included in the project, so you can parse the XML .csproj file to find all the .cs files.

From there, if you need to extract MethodInfo, you would have to either parse the .cs files, or use something like [Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) to parse the code into its syntax tree, and find the methods that way.

---

Can you just use the built assembly (.exe or .dll) from "Project B" instead of its .csproj file?  It would be a lot easier to load the assembly's reflection info, and just loop over every class and evey method...

Comment: I am working on source code recovery. I am interested in attributes usage. I can get that but what if source code is not compiled and we can not have its exe ? can we make use of asemblyInfo.cs

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can we make use of asemblyInfo.cs" That file typically just has a couple attributes in it, like version number, author, company, etc.  What exactly are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: I just need to extract all the attributes used in that project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Assembly.LoadFile` to load directly the compiled assembly - i.e. the DLL or EXE; this will give you an `Assembly` object on which you can call `GetTypes()` etc. to access all the info you want.

Comment: what if that solution is not compiled yet there would not be any .exe. Can we use AsemblyInfo.cs

Comment: -1 because the original post states "Project A provides a openFileDialogue and it selects .csproj file." so he isn't loading the built assembly.

Comment: @rally25rs: sorry, but it was not that clear (at least to two of us) that that was a requirement - I intepreted it as 'I tried this and then I got stuck'